# How to connect Navigation controller and Navigation Drawer in jetpack compose material 3?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm trying to link NavController and Navigation Drawer, but the emulator doesn't show what I'm switching.

route is included in the data class:

```
data class DrawerItem(
    val title: String,
    val selectedIcon: ImageVector,
    val unselectedIcon: ImageVector,
    val route: String
)
```

and then I try to navigate through the route in the item:

```
NavigationDrawerItem(
    label = { Text(text = item.title) },
    selected = index == selectedItemIndex,
    onClick = {
        navController.navigate(item.route)
        selectedItemIndex = index
        scope.launch {
            drawerState.close()
        }
    },
```

I run the code, but when switching items the driver closes and the screens do not change, the text with the name of the screen does not appear.